# Git rebase error VCS_INFO_get_data_git:225: no such file or directory: .git/rebase-apply/msg-clean

Tags: git

Rebasing the dev branch of a project gives the following errors

`VCS_INFO_get_data_git:225: no such file or directory: .git/rebase-apply/msg-clean`

So I was trying to update my local repos dev branch with the remote dev branch of this project https://github.com/appbaseio/abc/ using `git fetch origin master && git rebase origin/master` but I got the following error 
`VCS_INFO_get_data_git:225: no such file or directory: .git/rebase-apply/msg-clean` and now my zsh doesn't show the branch as `dev` but it appears to be in some detached head state showing a commit sha like this

`palash25@Lenovo-G50  ~/Dev/Projects/golang/gopath/src/github.com/appbaseio/abc  ➦ 6509b83 ●✚ >R>`

Comment: What is your `zsh` version?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)

Comment: Is there something missing? You had accepted the answer before.

Comment: No, I am sorry I must have thought that I hadn't clicked on it and unclicked the accepted sign. I use a dark theme in my browser so that must have been a reason for my confusion, I will accept it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a reported bug: [oh-my-zsh/issue 4932](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4932)

> This is a bug in zsh's codebase, [fixed in zsh-users/zsh@7a16787](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/7a1678767f44f200295d88dfea94902718275266).
>
> If you can, update your zsh to 5.2.

Comment: I'm on zsh 5.7.1 and I still have this issue.

Comment: @BrentO'Connor Then you can update https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4932 to report that: there might have been a new regression since 5.2.